# Make a GET request from within a Node.JS server app and send it to React.JS client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, get, request, koa

So I have a Koa / Node JS simple backend that is designed only to make a GET request to an external API, then pass the response body to the React JS client app I'm building. I'm new to Koa or any Node JS or server so couldn't really figure out how to.

Something like this:

```
var koa = require('koa');  
var app = koa();

app.use(function *(){ 
    http.get({host: somehost, path: somepath},
        function(response) {
            this.body = Here send to React Client
        }
    )
});

app.listen(3000);
```

edit: Answers using ExpressJS is also welcome.

Comment: [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) will bring you joy.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to funnel the response from the remote service to the client unaltered, you can pipe the response directly to the client.

```
'use strict'
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

app.use("/test", (clientRequest, clientResponse) => {
  http.get('http://some-remote-service.com', (remoteResponse) => {
    // include content type from remote service in response to client
    clientResponse.set('Content-Type', remoteResponse.headers['content-type']);

    // pipe response body from remote service to client
    remoteResponse.pipe(clientResponse);
  });
});

app.listen(3000,() => console.log('server started'));
```

One benefit of piping in this scenario is the client doesn't have to wait for the node.js server to receive the full response from the remote service before responding to the client - the client starts to receive the remote service response body as soon as the remote service starts sending it.